# IMPORTING Products - error "Skipping import row, required field "weight" for new products is not defined."?

Tags: error

Hi Ive seen the error for "sku" but not for "weight"?

Skipping import row, required field "weight" for new products is not defined.

Its in my xml file but i keep getting that error any one KNOW why?

FOUND IT

Weight

The Weight field is mandatory. If you don’t know the weight for this product, just enter 1.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/adding-a-new-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the solution is that if you don't want weight as required  then you can follow the steps

step 1 : looged in admin panel.

step2 : go to catalog >> attributes >> manage attributes.

step 3 : search "width" attribute. Open this attribute.

step 4 : you can see the in first tab you find validaion dropdawn like required . Please select no.

step 5 : refresh your cache and try to import again.

Comment: you welcome.....